# Тире или двоеточие (в вопросе с однородными членами)?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, двоеточие, вопрос

Интересует пунктуация в довольно распространённых вопросах типа:

*Какие задачи ты будешь выполнять (?) рутинные или креативные?*

Однородные члены после обобщающего слова или однородные члены, имеющие характер приложения/уточнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это  **пояснительная конструкция**, для обособления которой можно использовать разные знаки, при этом варианты будут различаться  интонацией.

При обособлении **запятой** пауза короче, чем в случае **двоеточия или тире**. Перед двоеточием делается понижение тона, а при постановке запятой или тире тон в первой части повышается, логическим ударением выделяется  слово ***задачи***.

Вариант с двоеточием встречается **реже**, чем два других варианта.

(1) Какие задАчи ты будешь выполнять, рутинные или креативные?

(3) Какие задАчи ты будешь выполнять  — рутинные или креатИвные?

(3) Какие задачи ты будешь выполнЯть: рутинные или креативные?

Примеры:

Какой цвет вы предпочитаете, белый или черный? [Сергей Корнев. Продавец в американском магазине (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.05.19]

Какой цвет лучше — белый или красный?

Comment: А я, наоборот, чаще встречаю вариант с двоеточием.

Comment: Здесь еще влияет объем первой части: при ее значительной распространенности  удобнее внутри сделать небольшую паузу, а перед обособленными определениями понизить тон, что соответствует постановке  двоеточия.

Comment: И кстати, хотелось бы добавить, что в случае с двоеточием пояснение сильнее подчёркивается (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123).