# Обособление пояснительной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, тире, двоеточие

*Вы будете выполнять различные задачи [ , / : / — ] от написания постов и создания фотоконтента до рекламы, взаимодействия с блогерами и общения с клиентами.*

Я уже задавал вопрос с предложением похожего типа ([Тире или двоеточие (в вопросе с однородными членами)?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440810/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)). Обособляется ли приведённая в предложении выше пояснительная конструкция по такому же принципу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вы будете выполнять различные задачи ― от написания постов и создания фотоконтента до рекламы, взаимодействия с блогерами и общения с клиентами.**

**Здесь запятая не подходит** в связи с распространенностью пояснительной конструкции и наличием собственных знаков препинания

**Лучше выбрать тире,** чтобы не делать предупредительной паузы, **да и по правилам здесь подходит именно тире**: распространенная пояснительная конструкция  в конце предложения.

**Розенталь**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто **ставится тире**: Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать — почитать (Г.); Разговор шёл один — о погоде; Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян;

Comment: «...Такие (следующие) задачи: написани**е** постов...» — видимо, опечатка.

Comment: Не будем ничего сравнивать, текст исправлен.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен, что по правилам больше подходит тире. Посмотрел в Нацкорпусе. Есть примеры с тире и двоеточием, примеры с запятой в основном касаются коротких  пояснений, хотя и тут нашлось исключение:

> Она помнила теперь всё своё прошлое, от самого раннего детства, от печки, обжигающей детские ладони, до последней страницы школьной тетради, в которой хромающими мучительными буквами был исписан десяток последних страниц… [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]
>
> Заявления, публикуемые СМИ, предрекали различные исходы: от благополучия российской экономики до её скорого краха. [Павел Иванов. Ключ к правовой экономике. Популярные хроники непопулярного закона // «Воздушно-космическая оборона», 2003]
>
> Диапазон наказаний широк― от штрафа в 500 минимальных размеров оплаты труда до 5 лет лишения свободы. [Евгений Толстых. Пивка для рывка (2003) // «Совершенно секретно», 2003.09.01]

Comment: В примере с двоеточием пояснительная конструкция нераспространенная и не имеет собственных знаков препинания, поэтому пояснительные отношения представлены наглядно. Если же пояснение распространено, содержит собственные знаки, то оно фактически имеет свою интонационную структуру, поэтому части предложения в этом случае лучше разделить тире.